# Passing custom launch arguments to detox

Tags: react-native, detox

I am struggling to pass launch arguments to detox. For example if I want to pass a few different users as launch args. My init file looks like:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.launchApp({
        newInstance: true, 
        permissions: {notifications: 'YES'},
        launchArgs: {
            users: {
                user1: { email: '123@abc.com', pass: '123456' },
                user2: { email: 'abc@123.com', pass: '654321' },
            }
        }
    });
});
```

However in my test file

```
await device.appLaunchArgs.get();
```

returns an empty object. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? Am i misunderstanding what launchArgs are for?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the launchArgs is to send parameters to the *app* being tested because you can't communicate with the app process otherwise. launchArgs enable you to configure specific app behavior, either (1) to pass dynamic parameters based on your test environment (e.g. ports of another process the app needs to connect to), or (2) to simulate a condition for a specific test case (e.g. you write two e2e tests, one that has some feature flag turned on and another one with it being off).

> However in my test file

You don't access the values in a test file. Since the test file runs in the same node process as the `beforeEach`, there's no need to pass args. In fact, you can launch the app (with the appropriate args) directly in your test case, which is especially useful for the case (2) above.

To read the launchArgs in the app, you can create an `.e2e.js` [mock file](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/guide/mocking), and then use [react-native-launch-arguments](https://github.com/iamolegga/react-native-launch-arguments) to retrieve the configured values. The rest is up to you but the general idea is to use the launch args in your app to change some part of business logic or configuration you want to test.

Comment: Awesome suggestion. Saved me alot of headache.